# wso2- how to send some values in a custom handler to backend service

Tags: header, wso2, handler, message

I 'm writing a custom handler in WSO2 and I need to send some parameter values (for example adding them to message header in handler) such that the parameter values can be accessed in back-end service. How can I do this? I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: what is the wso2-product you are using?

Comment: I am using API-Manager product

Answer (score 0):

Please refer[1] and get back for further questions.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Writing+Custom+Handlers